# Import tests from one Unit test target into another

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, continuous-integration

We started to split our swift iOS app into multiple frameworks to speed up our TDD feedback cycle. Each of these framework is a project with it's own unit test target. All of these are part of a larger workspace.

The issue is we can't run multiple test targets with our current CI setup. I was wondering if it's possible to bundle together all of our test targets into one for CI but keep them separated for development (maybe by importing/running tests from all the different targets into a "CI unit test target")?

Comment: Check out this article: https://noahgilmore.com/blog/xcode-shared-test-target/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly add another target and add REFERENCES to the files for the unit tests. They may more may not need modification of the module import names. A file may be referenced in multiple projects, and this could even be automated, as there are tools such as PBXProj for python to allow reading/writing of the Xcode project.

Alternatively, but I am not sure, it may be possible to create an aggregate target with the other items added - this is just speculation.

Perhaps a better question is why can't multiple test targets be run? Surely a script or fast lane could help?

Comment: I'll try sharing unit tests references, great idea thx. I've tried running all my tests in one script via xcodebuild but while that worked locally, it didn't ran on my CI.