# Xcode: merge Unit tests into a single target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, ios-frameworks

I'm developing a modular app with >30 modules, where each module has its own Unit test target. I also have a special test scheme which runs all Unit tests from all the targets.

The problem is - it's too slow. While the tests run fast, it takes a lot of time for Xcode to switch from one test target to another. The "all tests" scheme is supposed to be run in CI so I would really like to improve the performance.

I tried to convert all Unit test targets into static frameworks and link them to a new "merged" Unit test target. In this target I then created a single **AllTests.swift** file importing the frameworks and manually invoked tests on each of them. The performance improvement was ~4x.

However, this will be quite hard to maintain this file. My assumption is, since they are linked statically, there can be a way to make Xcode *run imported in such a way tests automatically*. If this works I'll be able to fully automate this process, keeping test targets for development and generating the "merged" target in CI.

What else I tried:

- Investigated the option of using **SourceKitten** to parse the project and generate the **AllTests.swift** file automatically. This would require building the project one more time, eliminating the performance improvement.
- Instead of linking frameworks, include references to source files into the merged target. This introduces a bunch of "multiple files with the same name" and "same declaration" errors that cannot be automatically resolved.
- Made all declarations in the static frameworks **public**.
- Googled a lot. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47297650/import-tests-from-one-unit-test-target-into-another) is quite close but the solution doesn't work for me.

So the main question is - is there a way to make Xcode automatically include Unit tests that are part of a static framework the current target is linked against? Or any other suggestion on how I can automate this process will be very much appreciated.

Comment: `it's too slow` what does "too slow" mean? If this is in the magnitude of seconds, then should be no problem on CI.

Comment: The "all tests" scheme runs in several minutes while the "merged" tests target runs in half a minute. The number of modules will grow so the performance will become worse.

Comment: That's odd, the difference should not be that big. Unless you have some scripts  that create and destroy simulators for every target.